# How to merge maps in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin, so sorry if this is very obvious.

Check this code:

```
val li = listOf("A", "B", "C")
fun foo(s: String): Map<String, int> {
   if(s == "A") return mapOf("A" to 1)
   if(s == "B") return mapOf("B" to 2)
   return mapOf("C" to 3)
}
fun bar(mp: Map<String, int>) {
  // Must be called once with mp = mapOf("A" to 1, "B" to 2, "C" to 3)
}
li.map {
   foo(it)
}.let {
   // I need to merge results from foo and call bar **only** one.
   // I cant change foo or bar
}
```

I know that this code returns `List<Map<String, int>>` but I want to get all the results in one Map, is there an elegant way to do so?

Comment: I am having a hard time following your example. What kind of logic do you want to achieve? Could you please make a concrete and **full example** with input and output? Downvoted bc unclear. It sounds like you want to flatten multiple maps into one, but what to do with conflicting keys?

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated the description

Comment: Your edit did not make it better. Please provide a full and concrete example of input/desired output. Also, you have not addressed the question regarding conflicting keys.

Comment: Better now? No conflicting keys

Comment: I have the feeling you do not understand what an example is. You are describing what you want to achieve with vague text, instead of literally showing an example of input/output. E.g. instead of saying _"i want to replace all vocals with 'x'"_, give an example `"hello world" -> "hxllx wxrld"`

Comment: Is this only an example and in your real code these maps you need to merge are much different? I ask because if `foo()` always returns a single-item map, then it would be much better to simply return an integer from it. It would be easier to implement and more performant to execute.

Comment: Much different but same logic, my real foo() returns map<Key, Value> that are much more complex than the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Map.plus` extension function to combine multiple maps into one:

```
listOf("A", "B", "C")
  .map { foo(it) } // List<Map<String, Int>>
  .reduce { left, right -> left + right } // Map<String, Int>
  .let(::bar)
```

Although in this case, it's probably more readable (and definitely more performant) to just use a loop:

```
val result = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
for (text in listOf("A", "B", "C")) {
  result.putAll(foo(text))
}
bar(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Jorn's answer as the solution to use, but as you're a Kotlin learner, it might interest you to see many different ways of doing this. All of the following lines return the same result:

```
li.map(::foo).reduce(Map<String, Int>::plus)
li.flatMap { foo(it).toList() }.toMap()
li.fold(mutableMapOf<String, Int>()) { map, s -> map.apply { putAll(foo(s)) } }
buildMap { li.forEach { putAll(foo(it)) } }
```

Answer (score 1):

In additional to Jorn's answer, you can use `flatMap()` to convert each map in the list into a `List<Pair<String, Int>>`

then use `toMap()` to merges the individual pairs into a single map.

```kotlin
listOf("A", "B", "C")
        .flatMap { foo(it).toList() } // List<Pair<String, Int>>
        .toMap()                      // Map<String, Int>
        .let(::bar)
```

Why I used `toList()`?

> To convert each map entry into a pair, because `flatMap()` expects a list as the result.

Also you can use `forEach()` to achieve the same result:

```kotlin
val result = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
listOf("A", "B", "C").forEach { result += foo(it) }
bar(result)
```